# Determine problem with CRON not running

Tags: ubuntu, cron

How can I determine any problems with the `/etc/crontab` not running cron commands?  I have scripts that send emails, I can run them manually via command line and they work great, but never get processed by cron....

What can I do to debug why cron isn't running?

I have a feeling this is part of the problem...

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/crond start
sudo: /etc/init.d/crond: command not found
```

Comment: It's `/etc/init.d/cron` not `crond` on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few options, not in any particular order.

- Run the command that you have in crontab on the command line.  This can be deceptive since oftentimes this will work for you, and the reason it's not running in cron is a missing environment variable, or something along those lines.
- Add an output option to your crontab line, for example:

  `5 */2 * * * /usr/local/bin/do-stuff.sh >> /tmp/results.log;`
- Make sure cron is actually running.
- Check your cron log files for any particular errors.

Comment: Don't forget: set `MAILTO` at the top of your crontab to point to some e-mail address that you actually check. (The default is to go to the local system account under which the cron job ran -- for `/etc/crontab`, probably root.

Comment: `MAILTO` is indeed actually set

Comment: How do I make sure that cron is actually running?  I can't find any cron log files or documentation on them, and nothing gets outputted or emailed given the output of these scripts.  I have verified that these scripts will run when I push them manually

Comment: The lazy way to check if cron is running is to simply run "/etc/init.d/cron restart" -- the output should indicate if it was running or not, and when you're done it should be running either way. Alternatively, something along the lines of "ps ax  | grep cron" should list cron, if it's running.

Comment: The right way would actually be `/etc/init.d/cron status`

Comment: ok, it says it's running

Comment: I would try adding logging at this point.  Also, perhaps outputting your crontab here would be helpful.

Comment: What debugging can I put in place?  I know with 100% certainty that these scripts are not being run automatically but function correctly when run manually.

Comment: I strongly suspect that if you send the output of your cron script to a file, you'll see an error message there, which will help you move forward.  If you need more specific help than the line I pasted up above, then post your crontab here and I can help you with it.  Cron scripts almost always run in a more restricted environment than your actual shell.  But it's hard to figure out what you will need to add without getting some sort of error feedback.

Comment: Got it, I enabled logging and that led me to the error, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @muffinista and @brent's answers, there are more esoteric problems you can run into on Ubuntu

- You need a blank line at the end of your crontab.
- The user must be in|not-in /etc/cron.allow|cron.deny (or have these files absent)

  - user does not need to be a member of group crontab
- cron may ignore filenames it doesn't like in /etc/cron.d/ and similar directories.

  - add cron's '-l' option (impact explained more in 'man run-parts')
- cron sends the crontab entries through /bin/sh (by default), so things as simple-looking as this will fail, but work when pasted into your /bin/bash terminal

  `0 * * * * echo hi >& /dev/null`

  so change SHELL or your redirection syntax!

My version of Ubuntu ignores settings in /etc/defaults/cron, so to bump up the log level you might need to run the cron daemon by hand (cron -f -L 2).

Answer (score 0):

In some recent cases, this has been due to people editing things in `/etc/crontab` without sending crond signal 1 (SIGHUP) to let it know that it should reread the `/etc/crontab` file.

Try

```
kill -1 $PID-OF-CROND
```

and see if that helps.  Determining the pid of crond is left as an exercise for you ;-)  - not least because if you can't find it, it may mean that crond isn't running, and then you'll have found your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using shellscript, people often forget that commands they use in their script may not be in cron's PATH (e.g., something in `/opt`). Setup your PATH properly at the beginning of your script as needed. For sh/bash, it would be:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/something-1.0/bin
```

for example

Comment: I've verified that the path is correct